# Count directories with a certain name that also contain file

Tags: powershell

I am currently working on a script that will count all of the directories (within a specified path, `\\servername\logs\failures`) which have a naming convention of "P0*" or "MININT*" - but the folders named as "MININT*" also must have a subfolder that contains a specified log file.  Also, it should only be counting folders created in the last 24 hours.

Here is my current code, it keeps returning a zero value and I am not sure why.  I have been searching for hours and tried different methods using recurse, `Test-Path`, etc. to no avail.

```
$imagefailures = Get-ChildItem '\\servername\logs\failures' -Directory | 
    Where-Object {
        ($_.Name -like "P0*") -or
        (($_.Name -like "MININT*") -and (Test-Path "\WinPE_TS_X_Win\SMSTSLog\Get-Name.log")) -and
        ($_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddHours(-24))
    } | Measure-Object | select -ExpandProperty Count
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$imagefailures = Get-ChildItem '\\servername\logs\failures' -Directory | 
    Where-Object {
        ($_.Name -like "P0*") -or
        (($_.Name -like "MININT*") -and (Test-Path "$($_.FullName)\WinPE_TS_X_Win\SMSTSLog\Get-Name.log")) -and
        ($_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddHours(-24))`
    } | Measure-Object | select -ExpandProperty Count
```

The path you are testing will always just be "\WinPE_TS_X_Win\SMSTSLog\Get-Name.log" if you do not append it to the folder path you are iterating on.

Comment: That did the trick.  I knew it was close.  :)  Thank you SO much for your help!